# ORA-00933: SQL Command not Properly ended (View Script)

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am getting this error

> ORA-00933: SQL Command not Properly ended

from the following view script. :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_SCRIPT AS (
SELECT * FROM
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what your query is supposed to do and it's quite large, so I'm not sure if this is logically what you want to acheive. but this should fix your syntax errors. I removed one paranthesis and added another (check comments).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_SCRIPT AS (
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        EFFECTIVE_DT,
        SOURCE_CD,
        VIEW_CD,
        SDEX_TRAN_CODE TRANSACTION_CD,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_DESC,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_TXT,
        'Y' TRANSACTION_CODE_ACTIVE_IND,
        Trunc(SYSDATE) TRANSACTION_CODE_START_DT,
        NULL TRANSACTION_REVERSAL_CD,
        NULL PRINCIPLE_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL INCOME_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL SHARES_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL COST_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        'INVEST1' ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_CD,
        NULL TRXDSCCD, 
        NULL USERDEFTRXDSC 
    FROM TRD_FPCMS_TRANS_FULL_01_STG
    WHERE SDEX_TRAN_CODE IS NOT NULL
    AND SOURCE_CD != 'INSTIO'
    UNION
    SELECT 
        EFFECTIVE_DT,
        SOURCE_CD,
        VIEW_CD,
        SDEX_TRAN_CODE TRANSACTION_CD,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_DESC,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_TXT,
        'Y' TRANSACTION_CODE_ACTIVE_IND,
        Trunc(SYSDATE) TRANSACTION_CODE_START_DT,
        NULL TRANSACTION_REVERSAL_CD,
        NULL PRINCIPLE_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL INCOME_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL SHARES_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL COST_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        'INVEST1' ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_CD,
        NULL TRXDSCCD,
        NULL USERDEFTRXDSC
    FROM TRD_FPCMS_TRANS_FULL_01_STG
    WHERE SDEX_TRAN_CODE IS NOT NULL
) stg
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM accounting_transaction_code tgt
    WHERE tgt.TRANSACTION_CD = stg.TRANSACTION_CD
)) -- removed paranthesis here...  -- try executing this query up
UNION
SELECT 
    businessdt effective_dt,
    holding_source_cd source_cd,
    holding_view_cd view_cd,
    txn.transaction_cd, 
    txn.tran_desc transaction_desc,
    'missing' transaction_category_txt,
    'Y' transaction_code_active_ind,
    TRUNC(sysdate) transaction_code_start_dt,
    NULL transaction_reversal_cd,
    NULL principle_multiplication_nbr,
    NULL income_multiplication_nbr,
    NULL shares_multiplication_nbr,
    NULL cost_multiplication_nbr,
    'GENEVA' ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_CD,
    tk.TRXDSCCD,
    tk.USERDEFTRXDSC
FROM transactions_gva_kfk_stg tks
JOIN cde_stg.TRANSACTIONS_IA_KFK_STG tk
ON tks.KAFKA_LOAD_ID = tk.KAFKA_LOAD_ID
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN LEAD(transaction_cd) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_cd) = transaction_cd
            THEN  substr(transaction_cd,1,6)||substr(sys_guid(),6,6)
            ELSE transaction_cd  END transaction_cd,
            tran_desc
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN (
                SELECT COUNT(1) 
                FROM accounting_transaction_code 
                WHERE transaction_cd =  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,12))
            ) = 0
            THEN  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,12))
            WHEN (
                SELECT COUNT(1) 
                FROM accounting_transaction_code 
                WHERE transaction_cd =  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,6)||substr(trxcd,-6))
            ) = 0
            THEN  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,6)||substr(trxcd,-6))
             ELSE substr(trxcd,1,6)||substr(sys_guid(),6,6)
            END transaction_cd,  tran_desc
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                gva.trxcd tran_desc, 
                regexp_replace(UPPER(trxcd),'[^A-Z0-9]') trxcd
            FROM transactions_gva_kfk_stg gva
            WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT 1
            FROM accounting_transaction_code tgt
            WHERE tgt.transaction_desc = gva.trxcd)
            ) gva
        ORDER BY transaction_cd
        )) txn -- added paranthetis here
ON txn.tran_desc = tks.trxcd
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM accounting_transaction_code tgt
    WHERE tgt.transaction_desc = tks.trxcd
); -- removed incorrectly added paranthesis here.
```

Comment: Thanks for this info. I made this update and the error changed to "sql command not properly ended"

Comment: I added an extra paranthesis by accident at the end, edited my answer so try again. But maybe explain what you're trying to acheive? it would help me find you a more accurate solution.